How to resume suspended upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04?
I was upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04 using Software Updater. Suddenly a window popped up showing a message regarding Thunderbird with a button named as Next. Upon clicking on Next, the window did not respond. After clicking it for a few times, another window opened with two options with either Force quit or Wait. Upon clicking on Wait for a while, it re-appeared repeatedly which made me to choose Force quit. Then the upgrade froze as shown in the screenshot at least 40 minutes before. What to do now?
Suspended upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04:


Try the following.
Open a terminal
Run in it
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt -f install
apt -m install
apt dist-upgrade
apt autoremove
apt clean
exit
sudo reboot

If any command gives error continue running the following and repeat the commands.

Thanks @kyodake for your reply.
